# Find value by any column in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have columns in table something like

```
answeremail,
    answertime,
    ata,
    atacomment,
    ataid,
    atainternalnumber,
    atanumber,
    atatype,
    author,
    becomeatafromdeviation,
    becomeexternalatafrominternal,
    becomefastfromothertype,
    briefdescription,
    city,
    client_answer_attachment,
    clientcomment,
    confirmstatus,
    created_at,
    deviation,
    deviationnumber,
    deviationtype,
    duedate,
    emailsent,
    financeid,
    forfortnox,
    fromfortnox,
    is_deleted,
    locked,
    name,
    parentata,
    paymenttype,
    pdfurl,
    projectid,
    quantity,
    reason,
    revisiondate,
    startdate,
    status,
    street,
    suggestion,
    token,
    type,
    unit,
    userid,
    zip
```

I want to create SELECT statment to retrive some of this column but without specify column name something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM ata WHERE 'field' = 'argument'
```

Is there any solution for this problem or either I need to specify all those column in SELECT statment ?

Comment: Do you know about [Native Dynamic SQL](https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/plsql/nds.html)? Perhaps it is appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunettly not, even not heard about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not (just) in `SELECT`, but in `WHERE`. Otherwise, how will query know which columns to check?

But - beware of datatypes. Oracle will try to implicitly convert one datatype to another. Sometimes, it'll succeed (e.g. to convert number `1` to string `'1'`), sometimes it'll fail (e.g. convert string `'A'` to number or string `'AB23F'` to `date` value).

Therefore, although you can try to write query which will write query for you, it might take some time to actually make it work properly. PL/SQL is probably what you'll end up with.

---

An example which checks all tables in my schema that contain a column named `PHONE_NUMBER` and searches for a row whose *phone number* contains `654`. This script returns tables that contain such a value; you'd return something else - list of columns? All columns? Can't tell.

That's just a starting point. Good luck!

```
DECLARE
  l_str VARCHAR2(500);
  l_cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
                FROM user_tab_columns u, user_tables t
                WHERE u.table_name = t.table_name
                  AND u.column_name = 'PHONE_NUMBER'
                                                            )
  LOOP
    l_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || cur_r.table_name ||
             ' WHERE ' || cur_r.column_name || ' like (''%654%'')';
                                                    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str) INTO l_cnt;

    IF l_cnt > 0 THEN
       dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt ||' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
    END IF;                         
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Could you provide some documentation or example it will be better to guide me a little bit and to better understand what you mean ? Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer and added a sample script I occasionally use. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is one short solution using xml:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5efc164b77a55b2ecf5d4bf85d589a5

```sql
select/*+ no_xml_query_rewrite */  *
from 
   xmltable(
      'for $row in ora:view("SAMPLE_DATA")
         let $col := $row/ROW/*[text() eq $search]
         where $col ne ""
       return element R {
         attribute X {$col},
         $row
       }'
      passing 
        'BB' as "search"
      columns 
         found_col varchar2(30) path '@X'
        ,row_data xmltype path '.'
   );
```

Results:

```
FOUND_COL                      ROW_DATA
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BB                             <R X="BB"><ROW><COLA>10A</COLA><COLB>BB</COLB><COLC>00</COLC></ROW></R>
BB                             <R X="BB"><ROW><COLA>10A</COLA><COLB>BB</COLB><COLC>10</COLC></ROW></R>
BB                             <R X="BB"><ROW><COLA>10A</COLA><COLB>BB</COLB><COLC>20</COLC></ROW></R>
BB                             <R X="BB"><ROW><COLA>10A</COLA><COLB>BB</COLB><COLC>30</COLC></ROW></R>
BB                             <R X="BB"><ROW><COLA>10A</COLA><COLB>BB</COLB><COLC>40</COLC></ROW></R>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you want to retrive the columns which spicified by the `where` clause only, and to omit the other columns.

I don't think this is allowed by simple sql statement. In the oracle document, at the *select_list* section, I can't see any solution for this question.

see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

If you really want, you can use pl/sql.

Comment: Yes, one possible solution is to use PL/SQL, but I forget to meansion in my question. :)